# Codeigniter form validation rules - required/min_length

Tags: codeigniter, validation

If i set the rule for a field as min_length[3], but no value for the field is passed as it is not a required field, would it throw me an error?

FOr eg:

```
array(
'field' => 'first_name',
'label' => 'First Name',
'rules' => 'min_length[2]'
),
array(
'field' => 'last_name',
'label' => 'Last Name',
'rules' => 'required|min_length[2]'
),
```

So my questions was, even if FirstName has no value entered by the user, would i still face an error with min_length is set to 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field will only be required if they have put one or more characters in the form field. If they leave it blank, it will pass.
so IF validation rules do not have **required** AND the user does not put anything in the form field -- it will pass.

But if they enter something in the field -- then the validation rules apply. If for example you have a min length of 4, if the user puts in 3 characters -- validation will fail. and the character count error will show up in the validation error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  From the [codeigniter doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html):

```
min_length  Yes Returns FALSE if the form element is shorter then the parameter value.  min_length[6]
```

If `FirstName` has no value entered, its length will be 0, which is shorter than the parameter value (2).  Therefore, it will return FALSE.